# PyQt : Creating variables from LineEdit

Tags: python, qt, soap, pyqt

```
import logging
import sys
import suds
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, QtNetwork
from service import Ui_Form
from suds.wsse import *

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.getLogger("suds.client").setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)
url = "http://xxxxxxxxx:xxxx/services/FireScopeConfigurationWebService/v1?wsdl"
token = UsernameToken("xxx", "xxxxx")
security = Security()
security.tokens.append(token)

client = suds.client.Client(url)
client.set_options(wsse = security)

class StartQT4(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Form()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.createButton,QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.create_srv)
        ciEditLine = QtGui.QLineEdit()        #variable 1
        str(ciEditLine.displayText())
        monitorEditLine = QtGui.QLineEdit()   #variable 2
        str(monitorEditLine.displayText())
        bolEditLine = QtGui.QLineEdit()       #variable 3
        str(bolEditLine.displayText())
        ipEditLine = QtGui.QLineEdit()        #variable 4
        str(ipEditLine.displayText())

    def create_srv(self):
        try:
                response = client.service.createConfigurationItem(ciEditLine, monitorEditLine, bolEditLine, ipEditLine)
                print response
        except WebFault, e:
                print e


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = StartQT4()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I am trying to take user input from the 4 LineEdit boxes in my GUI and use them as variables in my function for the web services call. But i am receiving this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "start.py", line 34, in create_srv
    str(ciEditLine.displayText())
NameError: global name 'ciEditLine' is not defined
```

ed

This is my first app so go easy thanks.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

William

Comment: Where are your widgets really? Shouldn't be self.ui.ciEditLine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to attach you reference to ths widgets to the objects, using `self`:

```
def __init__(self):
    ...
    self.ciEditLine = QtGui.QLineEdit()        #variable 1
    ...
```

Also, you need to pass the text value of the widget, not the widget reference:

```
def create_srv(self):
    try:
            response = client.service.createConfigurationItem(self.ciEditLine.text(), self.monitorEditLine.text(), self.bolEditLine.text(), self.ipEditLine.text())
```

Like this these references become attributes to your object and can be referenced later in any method by using `self`

Comment: Thanks that seems to have worked. The variables are not being passed into the XML client request. I can see it has &lt;PyQt4.QtGui.QLineEdit object at 0x2138950&gt as the variable...?

Comment: @WilliamFleming I updated the code. You need to pass the text value by calling the text() method of the widget. Passing the widget reference instead of its text value result in the representation of the widget reference you've seed.